# How to avoid duplicated entry when adding on database

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

how can i avoid to add duplicated entry in my database that is based on date? where instead of inserting again the duplicate entry, i will just update the old data to be deactivated and insert the new duplicate entry.

Here is the structure 
`Price table`

```
id        date_created        Value            is_active
1       2019-10-01 1:00:00      25                 0
2       2019-10-05 2:00:00      30                 0
```

but imagine that the user added a duplicated data again for the Price table which is like this.

`2019-10-05 3:00:00`

so what i want to do is to update the old entry that has the same date of the user entry to be `is_active 1` and insert the new entry.

is there a way to do this? doing this on PHP is really complicated for me because of the use of looping, but i think there is a way in MYSQL which i cant figure it out.

Comment: just compare created date and if not exist then perform insert operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> If you specify an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause and a row to be
>   inserted would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY
>   KEY, an UPDATE of the old row occurs.

In your case I suggest to you to do these steps:

- create a new column `date_time_created` as DATETIME
- convert `date_created` as DATE and save in it only the date

  e.g. `$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($yourDateTime));`
- set `date_created` as UNIQUE index:

  `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX date_created ON Price(date_created);`

---

```
INSERT INTO Price
(Value, date_created, date_time_created, is_active)
VALUES
('$theValue', '$date', '$dateTime', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is_active = 0
```

The conversion of `date_created` in DATE and the creation of `date_time_created` as DATETIME are necessary because is useless in your case to make a DATETIME unique because you need to check the value only by date. This also improve the readability and maintenance of your script.

Comment: i did what you said. and it had lessen the code that i had. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could first try to fetch the entry with the specific date and then update, otherwise insert.

You should also set the `date_created` column to `UNIQUE`.

Comment: The OP tells to do that with MYSQL, not PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Query the table and check if that date exists and is_actice = 1 and use the results to first update existing row then insert

Comment: The OP tells to do that with MYSQL, not PHP.